# Visual Studio tracing function navigation history in the editor

Tags: visual-studio

Tracing through code, I often want to see how I navigated to the current function. Is there a way in Visual studio to see the functions you followed to arrive at the current code?

For example,

```
Class A
------
main() {
  B.foo()
}
```

```
Class B
------
foo() {
  C.bar()
}
```

```
Class C
------
bar() {
 print("hello world")
}
```

If I wanted to know where "hello world" was printed I would

1. (In class A) Go To Definition on B.foo()
2. (In class B) Go To Definition on C.Bar()
3. See that "hello world" was printed in class C in the bar method.

By the time I get to Class C, I want to see the calls I followed to get there. Something like

```
A: main()
  B: foo()
     C: bar()
```

I'm not looking for the View.NavigateBackward shortcut, instead I want a way to see it all this information in one spot without having to change files.